# Create spark dataframe from multiple directories on S3

Tags: scala, apache-spark

basically I need to create a spark data frame from multiple directories on S3.

The directory structure under the root directory is as follows:

```
s3://some-bucket/data/date=2018-04-01/
s3://some-bucket/data/date=2018-04-02/
..
s3://some-bucket/data/date=2018-04-30/
s3://some-bucket/data/date=2018-05-01/
...
```

Now I need to create a data frame for specific dates (e.g. 10 days from 2018-04-26).

What's the best approach to do it?

I know I can create one data frame per directory (e.g. one for 2018-04-26, one for 2018-04-27, etc) and then union all data frames to get a single data frame. I'm not sure if there is extra overhead with this approach. Is there a way to specify a list of directories as input for data frame?

The programming language I use is Scala.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it in python. I am sure there will be scala equivalent for the same.

Spark read function uses variable length arguments feature to take multiple path as input.Call spark.read function with all paths separated by ','.

```
dataframe = spark.read.parquet(file1_path,file2_path,file3_path,...)
```

**FFR:**
What if you have all the path in a list? Just place asterisk before list while calling read function (* treats list as variable length arguments)

```
dataframe = spark.read.parquet(*file_path_list)
```